# CREATE_REACT_APP env variable in index.css

Tags: create-react-app

Want to do something like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova SemiBold';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url(%CREATE_REACT_APP_S3_BUCKET%"/fonts/ProximaNovaSemibold.otf") format('opentype');
}
```

It's not working. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use inline styles
2. Load different CSS files in the view depending on the environment variable.